# Why are the movie adaptations of the Robert Langdon book series in a random order?

Tags: book-adaptation, inferno, angels-and-demons, the-da-vinci-code

The movie adaptations of the [Robert Langdon book series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Langdon) have been released in the wrong order. The order of the books is *"Angels & Demons"*, *"The Da Vinci Code"*, *"The Lost Symbol"*, and then *"Inferno"*. But when it comes to the movies, *The Da Vinci Code* was filmed and released before *Angels & Demons* and *Inferno* will be next while *The Lost Symbol* hasn't been adapted yet.

Why are the movie adaptions in the wrong order?

Comment: There is little or no continuity between the books. Hence there is no reason to maintain the continuity while making the movies.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'd say that this order was prescribed by *The Da Vinci Code* (the book)'s high success. While Dan Brown might have been regarded as a best-selling author even before *The Da Vinci Code*, this book was a major success world-wide and gathered an attention much higher than *Angels & Demons* or any of his previous books did, I think. So it was just a matter of time till it got turned into a movie. And only later after a whole bigger crowd had noticed *Dan Brown* and after the *Da Vinci Code* movie was a big success, too, they are catching up on *Robert Langdon*'s previous adventures. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angels_%26_Demons_%28film%29) seems to support this to some degree:

> In 2003, Sony **acquired the film rights to Angels & Demons along with
>   The Da Vinci Code** in a deal with author Dan Brown. [...] Director
>   Ron Howard chose to treat Angels & Demons as a sequel to the previous
>   film, rather than a prequel, since **many had read the novel after The
>   Da Vinci Code**. He liked the idea that Langdon had been through one
>   adventure and become a more confident character. Howard was also more
>   comfortable taking liberties in adapting the story because **the novel
>   is less popular than The Da Vinci Code**.

But as to why *The Lost Symbol* was skipped for the movies, I don't have as obvious a theory, yet. Maybe it was to profit from the temporal adjacency to *Inferno*'s publication or maybe *The Lost Symbol* didn't sell too well (though that doesn't seem the case). But given the summaries on Wikipedia, it may also be that they wanted to continue *Robert Langdon*'s travel through the Old World and Renaissance history as in the previous movies, which *Inferno* seems to be pretty in line with. *The Lost Symbol* seems to tread quite a different path, having him on a chase through American history and Freemasonry in Washington D.C., a path that the *National Treasure* franchise already went rather successfully.

---

It also seems, that they indeed wanted to do *The Lost Symbol* after *Angels & Demons*, but changed their mind when *Inferno* was released in mid-2013. There were also issues with *Ron Howard* opting out for the supposed *The Lost Symbol* but rejoining when the plan switched to *Inferno* (along with screenwriter *David Koepp*?), so maybe that was a factor, too, as can be read [here](http://www.deadline.com/2013/07/sony-dates-latest-dan-brown-movie-inferno-for-december-2015-will-come-before-lost-symbol/):

> Tom Hanks and Ron Howard, the star and director, respectively, of
>   Sony’s first two tentpole movies based on Dan Brown’s novels, are
>   returning for Inferno, we’ve learned. **Hanks had been expected to
>   reprise his role as Harvard symbologist Robert Langdon for The Lost
>   Symbol**, the third novel in Brown’s book series. But **Howard had bowed
>   out of that project**, which is now on the back burner, saying he wanted
>   to produce it with Brian Grazer and their Imagine Entertainment but
>   not direct. Now we’re hearing **he’ll return for Inferno**.
>
> PREVIOUS BREAKING…Inferno was released in May and is the fourth Robert
>   Langdon book written by The Da Vinci Code and Angels & Demons author
>   Dan Brown. Sony, which has film rights to the franchise, has just set
>   a December 18, 2015 release date for it. **David Koepp, who wrote Angels
>   & Demons, is aboard to write the script**. The news means Brown’s third
>   installment of the thriller series, The Lost Symbol, will not be the
>   next movie for Sony. **Danny Strong had been set to write that
>   adaptation** in March 2012 and the expectation was the film would be
>   **directed by Mark Romanek after Ron Howard opted out** of directing as he
>   had done on the first two pics. Not much has been heard of that
>   project since, and now **Sony is leapfrogging it for Inferno**.